# Optimizing two level deep association count query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a visit model as following

```
class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :engineer
  has_many :machines
end
```

What i'm trying to do is find the number of machines associated with a particular engineer by using following code

```
count = engineer.visits.map(&:machines).flatten.size
```

is there any better and faster way to do this? I don't want to create a direct association between engineer and machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can for your query by using the model keywords like **join, includes**. while selecting one record form a model.

For your reference http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/7/7/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-easy-join-table-conditions, http://railscasts.com/episodes/202-active-record-queries-in-rails-3